# Is there a straightforward tool to manually rebuild a partition table on Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

Just now, I've accidentally wiped the first few GB of my hard drive. Luckily, this has happened before, and I added a buffer partition (which I don't care about) at the start of the drive. The overwrite only happened at that zone.

**I know the exact start and end offset of my actual data partition.** However, the last time this happened, I needed to recreate the partition using GParted on Linux. Is there an equally convenient tool on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I could not find a similar tool to Linux `fdisk`. As the data is fairly important, I opted to boot my Linux VM and worked from there, as I did before. The drive is restored without damage.

The closest I could find was [Active@ Disk Editor](https://www.disk-editor.org/index.html). It's freeware that could edit basically everything on a storage medium. However, it did not compute the Head-Sector-Cylinder automatically (which made Windows think the drive was unformatted), and I haven't learned how to do it manually yet.

Keeping the question open in case someone else can point to a tool that is as close as `fdisk` as possible, but on Windows.

- Can create partitions
- Is happy with being supplied only the start and end sectors
- Automatically computes the rest of what a partition entry looks like